# undefined/undefined with JS Values

Tags: jquery, datetime, datepicker

I have the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tzer0syu/2/

This works great, however when using with my primary form and the date plugin for bootstrap, the date and time fields wont update on change. The function and fields are named exactly as in the fiddle and no errors in console. Any ideas on what i can do to force the check for onchange? Is there a better way to do the check and ignore blanks if they exist?

Code below:

```
<input type="text" id="incidentDateTime" name="incidentDateTime" value="06/22/2016 1:30 PM" />
<input type="text" id="incidentDate" value="" />
<input type="text" id="incidentTime" value="" />

$(function () {
          function time1() {
            var dateTimeSplit = $('#incidentDateTime').val().split(' ');

            var dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('/');
            var currentDate = dateSplit[0] + '/' + dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[2];
            //currentDate is 18/10/2010

            $('#incidentDate').val(currentDate);

            var currentTime = dateTimeSplit[1] + ' ' + dateTimeSplit[2];
            //currentTime is 10:06 PM

            $('#incidentTime').val(currentTime);
    if (isNaN(incidentDateTime)) {
                     $("#incidentDate").val();
                } else {
                     $("#incidentDate").val(CurrentDate);
                }
            }
            $("#incidentDateTime").change(time1);
                 time1();
          });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is there a problem with the code in the JSFiddle, or is it only when you use this with Bootstrap or in some other context that you see the issue? Have you included enough code to show the actual problem?

Comment: Im using hidden fields with bootstrap and the fields will update if I give a value on page load calling the function. However when the field changes, the fields do not update the Date and Time. Is there a way to troubleshoot with console on why or some other method, rather than removing every script i have to find the culprit? The DOM isnt sending back the info to Chrome that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found the issue was the Bootstrap dateTimepicker plugin, here is the full code for those who may have the same issue: The main issue was checking for the onchange with the proper order: dp.change not change.dp

```
//Date Time Split Function
         $(function () {
          function time1() {
            var dateTimeSplit = $('#incidentDateTime').val().split(' ');

            var dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('/');
            var currentDate = dateSplit[2] + '-' + dateSplit[0] + '-' + dateSplit[1];
            //currentDate is 18/10/2010

            $('#incidentDate').val(currentDate);

            var currentTime = dateTimeSplit[1] + ' ' + dateTimeSplit[2];
            //currentTime is 10:06 PM

            $('#incidentTime').val(currentTime);

            }
            $('#incidentdiscovered').on("dp.change", function () {
                time1();
            });

          });
```